# Melvin Thumblr grid theme ( photo vs text)

Tags: gridview, tumblr-themes, blockquote, tumblr-html

Anyone please can help me with the following issue using a grid tumblr theme??

Worked fine for years but now SOME of the re-posts look like TEXT instead of PHOTO. I'm not an expert so don't know if can easily be fixed or not.

I just want to remove the paddings from the first post to look exactly the same as the other posts.

Thank you so much and please apologise if it's a silly question :)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16QLu.jpg)